# Multivariable limit $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x \sin(x^2 y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm learning multivariable calculus, specifically multivariable limits and continuity, and need help to understand the solution to the following problem:

> Let
>
> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x \sin(x^2 y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}, & (x,y) \neq (0, 0) \\ 0, & (x,y) = (0, 0).  \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$.

So we need to show that

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = f(0, 0)$$

that is

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x \sin(x^2 y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} = 0.$$

**Solution:** (from textbook)

We have that

$$\left| \frac{x \sin(x^2 y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}  \right| = \frac{\left|x\right| \left|\sin(x^2 y^2)\right|}{x^2 + y^2} \leq \frac{\left|x\right|x^2 y^2}{x^2 + y^2}  \leq \frac{\left|x\right|^3 y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \leq \left|x\right|^3.$$

**Question:**

I don't understand how the author found the upper bound for the sine function. Why does $\left|\sin(x^2y^2)\right| \leq x^2y^2$? When I first tried to solve this problem I used $\left|\sin(x^2y^2)\right| \leq 1$ without success. Can someone explein my error?

Comment: $| \sin x|\le |x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $t$, $$|\sin(t)|\leq |t|.$$
Indeed, using mean value theorem, for all $t$, there is $|c_t|\leq |t|$ s.t.
$$|\sin(t)|=|\sin(t)-\sin(0)|=\underbrace{|\cos(c_t)|}_{\leq 1}|t-0|\leq |t|$$

Answer (score 1):

Can i point out another strategy?
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x \sin(x^2 y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} = 0.
$$
changing to polar coords:
$$
\lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{\rho \cos t\, \sin(\rho^4 \cos^2t\,\sin^2t)}{\rho^2} = ... \textrm{taylor expansion} ... = 0
$$
of course the method in the textbook is valid, proof for the sin inequality:
$$
 |sin(t)|= \left| \int_0^t \cos(x) dx \right| \leq \left| \int_0^t \left| \cos(x) \right| dx \right| \leq \left|\int_0^t 1 dx \right| =|t|
$$
so for all $t \in \mathscr R$:
$$
|sin(t)| \leq |t|
$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically,
$$
(t-\sin t)'=1-\cos t\ge0
$$ then, since $0-\sin 0=0$, you get that
$$
t\ge \sin t, \quad t\ge0,
$$ and by parity
$$
|\sin t|\le |t|,\quad t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$